# How to fix custom AWS AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I am creating an AMI from ubuntu image and have installed some softwares.
I would require this AMI for running my automation scripts using AWS Datipeline. 
When I run use this AMI for creating Instance for execution, it always waits for dependencies. 
Can anyone please help me in resolving the issue??

Doing a deep dive into the logs, I found out that the job executor is not installed and that is the core issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is really funny how it worked but let me have a go.
I added an ec2-user using add-user and after that it found the job executor.
The real problem was that the job executor looks for ec2-user to execute itself.

It solved my problem ...